# View is running in CouchDb but returns empty result

Tags: view, couchdb, couchdb-futon, postman

In demo database ,following docs are stored...

```
{
  "_id":"biking",
  "_rev":"AE19EBC7654",
  "title":"Biking",
  "body":"My biggest hobby is mountainbiking. The other day...",
  "date":"2009/01/30 18:04:11"
}

 {
 "_id":"bought-a-cat",
 "_rev":"4A3BBEE711",
 "title":"Bought a Cat",
 "body":"I went to the the pet store earlier and brought home a little kitty...",
 "date":"2009/02/17 21:13:39"
 }

 {
  "_id":"hello-world",
  "_rev":"43FBA4E7AB",
  "title":"Hello World",
  "body":"Well hello and welcome to my new blog...",
  "date":"2009/01/15 15:52:20"
  }
```

Now on running following view which returns date and title from the document if exists...

```
 function(doc) {
    if(doc.date && doc.title) {
                 emit(doc.date, doc.title);
```

}
}

returns empty result..

```
{
 "total_rows": 0,
 "offset": 0,
"rows": []
```

}

...this result is not Expected....

Comment: all looks fine to me. I'd try amending the view to only return if doc.date or only if doc.title and then gradually identify the cause.

Comment: in order to Query need to run the views...this can be done through Futon or command line also                                       curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/demo/_design/demo1/_view/view1                                             ..@ Marcin Skorzewski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your documents are saved correctly in CouchDB, meaning you can query each of the document via the `GET`

> `http://127.0.0.1:5984/myDatabase/biking`

then we can scope down the problem area to either the M/R views and the actual query itself.

You're pretty much in the right direction when you said you're going to change the view to a simpler version.

You can verify your view is working correctly via futon's temporary view feature.

Once you've verify the view is working correctly, I'm assuming you're trying to call the view via `Postman`, one common issues when calling it through `Postman` is don't forget to put the login info in the url

> `http://username:password@127.0.0.1:5984/myDatabase/biking`

you can verify this by calling the built-in views e.g

> `http://username:password@127.0.0.1:5984/myDatabase/_all_docs`

Also make sure `reduce` is not being executed, you can specify this explicitly with `reduce=false` in your query.

Comment: at last i got the mistake..while storing the fields in the document i have put the fields in double Quotes and while Querying doc.title or any field...it was not able to access that..Silly me...thanks guys for your help....

Comment: @SunitaKumari could you tell me how you fixed the problem? I my case an error has been thrown(WARNING: Error executing view - null null) and i don't really now what it is wrong. Thank you!